# The variance of a biased estimator

Tags: regression-coefficients, bias, estimators

This builds on an [an earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530866/understanding-convergence-of-ols-estimator) from Math SE. I am just starting to learn about the simple regression model. In particular, I am trying to understand what happens to $\hat{\beta_1}$ when the $E(e|x) = 0$ assumption is violated.

For a large sample, the equation for a biased estimator in this case is

\begin{equation}
\hat{\beta}_1 = \beta_1 + \frac{{cov(e,x)}}{{var(x)}}.
\end{equation}

I want to know if the variance of $\hat{\beta}_1$ is bigger or smaller when the assumption is violated. If it *isn't* violated, then $\hat{\beta}_1 = \beta_1$ and $var(\hat{\beta}_1) = var(\beta_1) = 0$ since $\beta_1$ is a constant. If it *is* violated, then the equation is

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
var(\hat{\beta}_1) & = var(\beta_1) + var\bigg(\frac{{cov(e,x)}}{{var(x)}}\bigg) \\
& = 0+var\bigg(\frac{{cov(e,x)}}{{var(x)}}\bigg)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

But both $cov(e,x)$ and $var(x)$ are constants, which implies $var(\hat{\beta}_1) = var\bigg(\frac{{cov(e,x)}}{{var(x)}}\bigg) = 0$.

This is not the result I expected. Intuitively, I expected the variance to be greater in the biased case because it is a worse estimator of the actual value. In other words, the biased estimator is "more off" of the correct value so the variance would be larger.

Comment: If you're still assuming $e$ are iid, then a nonzero expectation simply gets absorbed in the constant term $\hat\beta_0$ and has no effect at all on $\hat\beta_1$.

Comment: The key to resolving your confusion about the variance of a biased estimator is that the variance of the (biased) estimator is relative to the expected value of that (biased) estimator, not relative to the true parameter value.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thank-you, I think I see now. The analogy I found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimator#Variance) was also useful. I am still uneasy that my calculation of 0 variance is correct for both cases... I apologize, but I feel I need to ask: do you think I am making an error somewhere in the calculation itself?

Comment: The statement: "If it isn't violated, then $\hat{β}_1=β_1$" is untrue.